# Component should cover the entire parent element

Tags: css, angular, progress-bar

I try to create a progress bar component in angular, everything is working except covering the parent element.

See the working code here:

See the code: [Angular code: what I have now](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-knz5ix?file=src/app/app.component.html)

CSS:

```
:host {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

:host> .loader {
  border: 3px solid rgba(126, 132, 138, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 3px solid red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite; /* Safari */
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1010;
  opacity: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Simple HTML:

```
<div class="loader"  *ngIf="isLoading"></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need a bit of CSS:

```html
<h3>
  Want this progress bar to cover the parent div area <br />
  that mens dotted area(page-section)
</h3>
<div id="page-section">
  <div class="example-loading">
    <app-loader></app-loader>
  </div>

  <h4>Form Controls</h4>
  ...
</div>
```

```css
.example-loading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

[StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5m2ie2?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to go is changing the parent css behaviour, instead of the loading component.

Change your `.page-section` class like that in `app.component.css`

```
#page-section {
  border: 3px dotted #bbb;
  position: relative;
}
```

Then wrap the loader component in a tag with the following style

```
.loader-container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

This essentially makes the container take the whole space available and vertically and horizontally center its content.

[Here](https://angular-ivy-ksug6w.stackblitz.io) is your code updated.